# ASP.NET Identity - setting UserValidator does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to set the `UserValidator` for the default `ApplicationUserManager` in a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project (using ASP.NET Identity 2).  I've created a very simple UserValidator:

```
public class SimpleUserValidator<TUser, TKey> : IIdentityValidator<TUser> where TUser: class, IUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey> {
    private readonly UserManager<TUser, TKey> _manager;

    public SimpleUserValidator(UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager) {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(TUser item) {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.UserName))
            errors.Add("Username is required");

        if (_manager != null) {
            var otherAccount = await _manager.FindByNameAsync(item.UserName);
            if (otherAccount != null && !otherAccount.Id.Equals(item.Id))
                errors.Add("Select a different username. An account has already been created with this username.");
        }

        return errors.Any()
            ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray())
            : IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I set this by calling:

```
manager.UserValidator = new SimpleUserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager);
```

within the `ApplicationUserManager.Create()` method.

The problem is, this doesn't change the behavior.  I still get the default `The Email field is not a valid e-mail address` message.  Is this not the correct place to set that validation?

Comment: Did you try stepping/debugging into this method (e.g. set a breackpoint in it)? Is it getting called?

Comment: No, it's not.  That's part of what's confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this question and the answer here is not quite right so I am adding mine here to share.

The issue was caused by setting the `UserValidator` inside the Create function. Since I was newing an instance of the `ApplicationUserManager` the default validator was being used. Moving the application validation setting to the constructor solved the problem. The Create function should only have the option specific settings I think.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationUserManager"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="store"></param>
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        UserValidator = new ApplicationUserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
            RequireUniqueEmail = false
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the specified options.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">The options.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context.Get<MyContext>()));
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

**Alternatively** you could remove all instances of `new ApplicationUserManager`, and call Create instead. But that is dificult to enforce on others using your code without making the constructor private

Making the constructor private would make seeding the user table difficult because the `IOwinContext` is not available in the seeding function. Also you would not be able to unit test your `ApplicationUserManager` by passing a mocked store during construction.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  And it should have been obvious.

The `UserValidator` is not the only thing you have to change for validation from a new template.  You also must change all the relevant view models.  Go figure.