# ASP.NET Identity - Custom role validation not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-identity-3

I am trying to the create a custom `RoleValidator` object to validate my custom `IdentityRole`. I have created an `ApplicaitonRoleValidator` class that inherits from `RoleValidator` and set this as the `RoleValidator` in my `ApplicationRoleManager` class. But when I create new role the validation function `ValidateAsync` is never called.

I have tried looking at similar questions implementing `UserValidator` like [How can customize Asp.net Identity 2 username already taken validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655578/how-can-customize-asp-net-identity-2-username-already-taken-validation-message)
and this one [ASP.NET Identity - setting UserValidator does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509087/asp-net-identity-setting-uservalidator-does-nothing) but cannot get it to work.

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom role validator, used to validate new instances of ApplicationRole that are added to the system.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TRole">The type of the role.</typeparam>
public class ApplicationRoleValidator<TRole> : RoleValidator<TRole> where TRole : ApplicationRole
{
    private RoleManager<TRole, string> Manager { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationRoleValidator" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="manager">The manager.</param>
    public ApplicationRoleValidator(RoleManager<TRole, string> manager) : base(manager)
    {
        Manager = manager;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates a role before saving.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">item</exception>
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(TRole item)
    {
        if (item == null)//<= break point here never reached.
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }

        var rslt = base.ValidateAsync(item);
        if (rslt.Result.Errors.Any())
        {//return error if found
            return IdentityResult.Failed(rslt.Result.Errors.ToArray());
        }

        var errors = new List<string>();
        //validate the min num of members
        if (role.MinimumNumberOfMembers < 0)
        {
            errors.Add(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "最小数は0以上でなければなりません。"));
        }

        return errors.Count > 0 ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()) : IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

`ApplicationRoleManager` where the custom `RoleValidator` is set during create. I can break on that line so I know it is being called.

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole, string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationRoleManager"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="store"></param>
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the specified options.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">The options.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new ApplicationRoleStore(context.Get<MyContext>()));
        manager.RoleValidator = new ApplicationRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>(manager);
        return manager;
    }
}
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public bool IsSystemGroup { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
    public int MinimumNumberOfMembers { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleStore(MyContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

The role is being created by call to Create on the ApplicationRoleManager

```
var store = new ApplicationRoleStore(new MyContext());
var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(store);
manager.Create(group);
```

Comment: I am trying to do this in ASP.NET Core with dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the ApplicationRoleValidator as RoleValidator of ApplicationRoleManager in **Create** method of ApplicationRoleManager. In the 3 last lines of code you posted, you are **newing** an instance of ApplicationRoleManager. This instance of ApplicationRoleManager gets the **default** RoleValidator.

If you want to new an instance of ApplicationRoleManager you have to put that logic inside constructor

```
public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> store) : base(store)
{
     RoleValidator = new ApplicationRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>(this);
}
```